# C# Typed Datasets and Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I've not used typed datasets before ....

I have a dataset and I want to add a row.

I tried this:

DataRow dr = dataGridView_Checks.NewRow();
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);

Says it cannot resolve symbol NewRow.

How do I add a row to dataGridView_Checks so that it updates my dataset?

Also, how do I access the instantiated dataset? I didn't create it but I can add and and delete items to it at runtime.

Thanks as always.

Comment: "I've not used typed datasets before ...." - Then why start (a bad habit) now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DataSet does have a NewRow method. Did you tried [DataTable.NewRow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?